# Is Accessing WSL2 Filesystem from Ubuntu Dual Boot Safe? Need Advice!

Tags: dual-boot, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've been exploring the idea of accessing the WSL2 filesystem directly from Ubuntu in a dual-boot setup with Windows. The concept involves mounting the WSL2 virtual hard disk (VHD) from Ubuntu to interact with the files stored within the WSL2 environment. This process could potentially streamline workflows that span both operating systems. ChatGPT tells me, this is risky, but won't provide sources, and i do not find much online. It thinks read-only is a good idea, but that would make it kinda useless.

It recommends it like this:

```
sudo apt install libguestfs-tools 
sudo guestmount -a /path/to/your/WSL2-distro.vhdx -m /dev/sda --ro /mnt/wsl2
--ro .. read-only
```

Anyone tried this? Success stories or cautionary tales welcome. Looking for advice or insights to do this safely.

Thanks!

Comment: I’m tempted to say if chatGPT says it’s risky, then it’s probably completely safe ;) - but that doesn’t help you much!

Answer (score 1):

With a raw disk image (`.img` and `.iso` files), you can just mount it in the simple manner. Things are more complicated with other formats, like the VHDX format mentioned here.

You can expose the contents of the various VM disk formats as a Unix block device using `qemu-nbd`. From here you can proceed with the usual disk management procedures. Partitions of NBD devices are numbered `/dev/nbdXpY`, similar to how NVME partitions are named.

```
# modprobe nbd
# qemu-nbd -c /dev/nbd0 -f vhdx /path/to/your/WSL2-distro.vhdx
# mount /dev/nbd0p1 /mnt
```

`qemu-nbd` is part of the `qemu-utils` package:

```
# apt-get install qemu-utils
```

The “risky” part from ChatGPT likely comes from its digestion of [guestmount](https://libguestfs.org/guestmount.1.html)'s man page, where there is a big warning regarding mounting volumes actively used by virtual machines, a major source of race conditions. Since only one operating system can be running on the bare metal at any given time, the race condition risk does not exist, and you can safely mount it read-write. I do not recommend using it; the usage of FUSE makes it slower than kernel filesystem drivers.

Comment: Nice thank you, the explanation makes sense, I tried it and it works seamless. 
Do you think it should be unmounted every time I shut down linux or does it not matter?